# Sort the rows of the array by the value of the element of the main diagonal in each of the rows (in the initial array)

Tags: arrays, ruby

Sort the rows of the array by the value of the element of the main diagonal in each of the rows (in the initial array)

```
[[3, 2, 7, 1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8],
[5, 3, 7, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 6, 7],
[1, 9, 7, 8, 2, 1, 3, 7, 9, 8],
[1, 7, 3, 7, 6, 6, 6, 8, 4, 8],
[4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6]]
```

There is such an array, how should it look as a result?

Comment: Hint: `with_index` and then a custom `sort_by`.

Comment: Your example array has fewer "rows" than "columns", so it has no main diagonal.